Plane motion of solids and compound rotation
In plane motion of a rigid body, there will always exist a point (on or outside the body) rigidly fixed to this body, such that, at any given moment, the motion of the solid can be represented as pure rotation about an instantaneous axis passing through that point.
...(1)
Now, when a body is rotating simultaneously about two intersecting axes (say OA and OB), we can represent the rotation as rotation about a single axis (which need not be stationary). Direction coincides with the vector sum of angular velocities.
...(2)
My question is, is the axis obtained by angular velocity summation the same as finding the axis passing through the special point (mentioned in para 1) and point O(intersection point of the two axes)?
